# Use AWS "Native Services" or docker images of what I need?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Say you deployed on AWS and you had a Kubernetes application with multiple components/docker images. You can use AWS's RDS or Redis services, or you can instantiate your own dockerized components to do the same thing. Is there any best practice to know when to choose to say RDS by AWS, or simply use the latest docker image for the database of your choice?

I realize letting AWS manage RDS is probably easier and more stable than instantiating your own docker image of a database, managing the volumes for it and so on. But is there any consideration I am missing?

Comment: Cost and vendor lock-in are the other usual considerations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main considerations would be to use docker if you want to be able to easily and quickly move your application to other hosting locations like Azure, GCP, Digital Ocean, on-premise, etc.

If you want Amazon to manage the servers for you, with the absolute minimal effort on your part, use RDS.